# Extracting from DB in multithreads to txt file

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc

I need to improve performance of extracting huge DB table.
The table is partitioned.

For now I am extracting via jdbc connection and writing to text file iterating ResultSet.

I am planning now to create multiple connection each one in it's thread, each connection will run select query per partition:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE  partition (PR001_P1)
SELECT * FROM TABLE  partition (PR002_P2)
SELECT * FROM TABLE  partition (PR003_P3)
```

each thread will write to a thread-safe buffer, another thread will read from this buffer and write to file (order is not important)

Will it improve the performance? (I know that I need to test but maybe you can advise)

Comment: Yes, do you have any specific doubts?

Comment: at a high level your approach is correct. Dont keep your resultsets in the thread safe buffer but create your DO or VOs int he thread from the resultset and add those VO/DOs to the buffer (List or queue or whatever you want). This decouples the data producer form the data consumer and is a good approach.

Comment: @Nazgul, yes I am planning to map resultset to some object and put this object in queue.

Comment: then it should improve performance considerably.

Comment: Advice? Don't put Java and thus data transfer between processes into the mix (possibly over a socket) - let the DBMS be directly responsible for dumping the data to a file.

Comment: @Gimby, it's not a straight forward dump as it requires some logic on the extracted field before writing them to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ***likely*** to improve performance, but you will only be able to tell if it does by testing it.

You are betting that the amount of time that is spent waiting for IO when writing to the output file is less than the time that you gain by executing the requests in parallel. Seem like a fairly safe bet to me.

The memory footprint of your process is likely to be bigger than the single threaded approach. It'll be worth keeping an eye on that as, if you get to a point where you are memory constrained, you could find that that impacts you performance.

Comment: memory/ diskspace is not a problem